# What is the formula behind Excel's PERCENTRANK.EXC?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I noticed `PERCENTRANK.INC = count below / (count below + count above)`

[image]

But what is the formula for `PERCENTRANK.EXC` that makes it go from 1 to 99 (exclusive) instead of 0 to 100 (inclusive)?

Comment: You have the spreadsheet. Have you looked at the cells to see what formula is in there?

Comment: It's better show us the formula for PERCENTRANK.EXC column. Then we could explain the  mathematical formula, according to the arrary value and X value.

Comment: The formula for the PERCENTRANK.EXC column is the built-in function: `=PERCENTRANK.EXC($A$2:$A$11,A2,8)` I'm wondering how it's actually calculated.

Comment: I think the formula is `=A2/11`. There is 10 numbers which could be divided into 11 equal parts, if the X value is 10, then there are 10 equal parts less than 10, so the formula is "10/11".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is wrong, and breaks down when you have repeated numbers in the array, especially for the highest or lowest values.

As far as I can tell, these are the "formulas" for inclusive or exclusive ranking:

Percentrank.INC == Count Below / (Number of array elements -1)

Percentrank.EXC == (Count Below +1) / (Number of array elements +1)

As the number of elements increases, the plus or minus 1 becomes less significant, so for very large datasets the values converge.